# Joined table not available in select using CASE WHEN EXISTS ()

Tags: sql-server

I found out that the code below doesn't work. In "CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2)", the T2 table is not available. I'm now would like to understand why it's not available and some suggestions on who to write a better code. I know I can replace this with "CASE WHEN T2.cnt>=1", but I ws planning on not having the cnt column in the join sub-select from the start

```
SELECT T1.*,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2) THEN "ONE" ELSE 'TWO' END AS 'Test'
FROM T AS T1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT T.BK, count(*) as cnt
    FROM T
    WHERE T.filter > 50
    GROUP BY T.BK 

) as T2 on T1.BK = T2.BK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't reference `T2` in that subquery in your `SELECT`, as `T2` is an alias of a subquery in your `FROM`; it has no context in that subquery. It looks like, however, you don't need that subquery in the `FROM`, and it should just be in the `EXISTS` as you don't return any of the columns from `T2` in your `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT T1.*, --Define your columns, rather than using *
       CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM T T2
                         WHERE T2.filter > 50
                           AND T1.BK = T2.BK) THEN 'ONE' ELSE 'TWO' --I assume you mean 'ONE'. Double quotes (") are for object names
       END AS Test --Don't use single quotes (') for object names/aliases, they are for literal strings
FROM T AS T1;
```

If the above is correct, then you don't even need a subquery though, you could use some windowed conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT T1.*, --Define your columns, rather than using *
       CASE COUNT(CASE WHEN T1.filter > 50 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.BK) WHEN 0 THEN 'TWO' ELSE 'ONE' END AS Test
FROM T AS T1;
```